# Google Script issue with Delete, Rename, Copy workflow

Tags: google-apps-script

In this spreadsheet there are 3 sheets.  One called Juniper, one called Archive Juniper, and one called Template Juniper.

On a daily basis staff fill out the Juniper form.  On a time based trigger I need delete the old "Archive Juniper", rename "Juniper" to "Archive Juniper", and copy "Template Juniper" to "Juniper".  Effectively it just archives yesterday's and creates a new blank one based off of a template.

My code is below.  It worked very well for quite a white but a few days ago it stopped working.  I'm not a programmer so any help would be fantastic.  I'm getting an invalid argument error on the `ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(mainSheet));`

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var templateSheet = 0;
var template = 0;
var mainSheet = 0;
var archive = 0;
var templateSheet = 0;
var sheet = 0;

mainSheet = ('Juniper');
template = ('Template '+mainSheet);
archive = ('Archive '+mainSheet);
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(archive));
ss.deleteActiveSheet()
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(mainSheet));
ss.renameActiveSheet(archive)
templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName(template);
ss.insertSheet(mainSheet,ss.getSheets().length,{template:templateSheet });
ss.moveActiveSheet(1);
```

Sorry for the ugly code, I'm awful at best.

-Jon

Answer (score 0):

That error should only occur if the script can't find a sheet with the name 'Juniper' and returns null into the method that makes it active. I've cleaned up the code a bit to remove the extra stuff, can you tell us if this works?

EDIT: I tried it out and had issues, too. The code below works for me.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var mainName = "Juniper";
var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName(mainName);

var templateName = "Template " + mainName;
var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName(templateName);

var archiveName = "Archive " + mainName;
var archiveSheet = ss.getSheetByName(archiveName);

ss.setActiveSheet(archiveSheet);
SpreadsheetApp.flush();//Makes sure the sheet is active before deleting
ss.deleteActiveSheet();

mainSheet.setName(archiveName);

//Inserts it as first sheet, so no need to move it
ss.insertSheet(mainName,0,{ template : templateSheet });
```

Comment: I'm still getting Invalid argument at ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(mainSheet));

It seems that any time I delete a sheet and then set a new active sheet I get that error. If I was to take the "deleteactivesheet" out of that code the rename would then start working.

I ran a log on it and the first set active works. The delete works, but when you set the second active sheet it return null.

Thanks! -Jon

Comment: try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` after deleting a sheet. That forces the Spreadsheet to finish what you asked before moving on to the next step.

Comment: Same issue. I have no idea whats going on with this code.  Is there another way to write it maybe?

Comment: I just updated my answer with something that worked for me. I had the issue as you for some reason I just can't see.

Comment: Great, i'll try that tomorrow.  Thanks Frederic.

Comment: Looks like you set the mainsheets as variables.. that's a fantastic idea!  I definitely wouldn't have thought of it

Comment: [13-04-29 22:06:47:416 CDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0.0 seconds]
[13-04-29 22:06:47:470 CDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([High School IV]) [0.053 seconds]
[13-04-29 22:06:47:501 CDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Template High School IV]) [0.084 seconds]
[13-04-29 22:06:47:539 CDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Archive High School IV]) [0.122 seconds]
[13-04-29 22:06:47:539 CDT] Spreadsheet.setActiveSheet([null]) [0.122 seconds]

Comment: It looks like the variables set right, but when you do spreadsheetsetactive it returns null.

Comment: It's so weird.  It's like the script will run fine a few times, but then start giving me that error again.

Comment: Yeah, it's really weird. It's not `.setActiveSheet()` that's returning null, but a `.getSheetByName()`, which is then passed into `.setActiveSheet()` which fails because it can't accept null. Try reporting it to the issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list